# Plotting wind vectors arrows from U and V rasters in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, plot

I have a 'U' and 'V' rasters for wind direction and I want to plot wind direction arrows in QGIS. This is easy to do in Python/matplotlib with the `matplotlib.pyplot.quiver` function, but I can't find a similar way in QGIS?

Existing questions deal with Plugins that are no longer available and/or CSV point input data.

Answer (score 1):

What i would recommand will be to tranform your raster to points and then do the styling of your wind arrows. You will get a lot of option to define styling of your arrows.

1. In the toolbox use the tool Raster pixel to points (in the folder vector creation).
2. With the result of the process you should get U and V value on the attribute table of your point layer. If you have to separate layer merge the points with nearest neighboors tools.
3. When you have one point layer with U and V, set the symbol to be a vertical arrow then set the size to be based on expression `sqrt ("u"*"u" +"v"*"v"` and the angle to be something like `degrees( atan2("u","v"))`

PS : there is a type of feature that QGIS handle called mesh that may be used to work on wind.